# Are functions that carry proofs with them better than those that do not?

Tags: specifications, agda, dependent-type

Are functions that carry proofs with them better than those that do not?
In particular, with the setting:

```
data Fin : ℕ → Set where
  zero : ∀ {n} → Fin (suc n)          
  succ : ∀ {n} → Fin n → Fin (suc n)


Fin′ : ℕ → Set
Fin′ n = Σ m ∶ ℕ • m < n    -- Σ∶• = Data.Product.Σ
```

There is an isomorphism between the two types and it can be achieved directly by

```
toFin : ∀{n} → Fin′ n → Fin n
fromFin : ∀{n} → Fin n → Fin′ n
```

which merely embed one into the other, and then we have

```
fin-sound  : ∀ {n} {m : Fin′ n} → fromFin(toFin m) ≡ m   
fin-sound˘ : ∀ {n} {m : Fin n} → toFin(fromFin m) ≡ m
```

However, we can define more constrained versions of `toFin` and `fromFin`:

```
fin : ∀{n} → (m′ : Fin′ n) → Σ m ∶ Fin n • (m′ ′) ≡ (` m)
fin˘ : ∀{n} → (m : Fin n) → Σ m′ ∶ Fin′ n • (` m) ≡ (m′ ′)
```

where the pre- and post-quote are the obvious forgetful functors:

```
_′ : ∀{n} → Fin′ n → ℕ
`_ : ∀{n} → Fin n → ℕ
```

and as before, more-or-less, we can show

```
fin-soundness : ∀{n}{m′ : Fin′ n} → proj₁(fin˘(proj₁ (fin m′))) ≡ m′    
fin-soundness˘ : ∀ {n} {m : Fin n} → proj₁(fin(proj₁ (fin˘ m))) ≡ m
```

**Now the question is which approach is better and why?**

The first is straight-forward in terms of setup, but then the soundness proofs were a bit lengthy. Whereas the second approach required a bit more setup, via forgetful functors and whatnot, but the ensuing soundness proofs were rather short.

Any insight is appreciated :-)

Comment: Could you show your code? I don't see a reason for "the soundness proofs were a bit lengthy".

Comment: Source code :: http://pastebin.com/nGnwM1hC

Comment: Your proofs are lengthy because you made them so. If you remove equational reasoning, you'll get [short](http://lpaste.net/147183) proofs.

Comment: Woah! Nice proofs, thank-you.

Also, I get that my equational reasoning had a lot of  empty refl, ==<>, steps and so removing them makes things shorter. But your proofs are slick ;)